# How to get intellisense for middleware of express in external file in vscode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm trying to write a middleware of express. And I wrote that in a single file test2.js

In the server, I can have intellisense like:

[image]

In that single file, the middleware works fine, but I can't have intellisense of **req and res**

**Is there any way to get the intellisense?**

---

Here is my server **test1.js**:

```js
//test1.js
let http = require("http");
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

let middle = require("./test2.js");
app.use(middle);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Here is my middleware **test2.js**:

```js
//test2.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("middle");
  next();
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe JSDoc is an option?
You might need to install the type definitions: `npm i @types/express -D`
("Automatic Type Acquisition" in VS Code may or may not do that for your automatically)

```
/** @type {import("express").RequestHandler} */
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    req. // intellisense works
    next();
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript

---

#### You can also use your own typescript declaration file:

myTypes.d.ts

```
import Express from "express";
declare global { 
    type RequestHandler = Express.RequestHandler;
}
```

Types are usually bound to the module's scope, but you can import any type and re-declare it in the global scope.

Now vscode finds the types without the "dirty" `{import("express")}`

myMiddleware.js

```
/** @type RequestHandler */
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    req. // intellisense works
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ippi, the method using typescript declaration file works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, Typescript declaration file works but i noticed that it only works when the `myTypes.d.ts` file is open in the editor, maybe it's only for me but had to do `/// <reference path="./mytypes.d.ts" />` in order to get the intellisense to work.